# How to Transpose Dictionary Names from one module into Dictionary Keys in another module?

Tags: python, dictionary, import, transpose

I have a set of values belonging to users that will be parameters to a given function. There are multiple groups I'll be comparing and each has their own set of assumptions - about 80% of the time they will be common variables (though not the values themselves).

I'll be adding a new variable more frequently than a new user so I'd rather bundle in data as a dictionary for each variable.

How can I best traverse the assumptions data to compile a dictionary for a given user?

In other words, from here:

**assumptions.py**

```
var_x = {'user_1': 10, 'user_2': 15, 'user_3': 12}
var_y = {'user_1': 1000, 'user_3': 950}   # nothing for user_2
var_z = {'user_1': 3, 'user_2': 2, 'user_3': 3}
```

to here:

**foobar.py**

```
user = 'user_2'
<transpose>
user_dict = {'var_x':15, 'var_y':None, 'var_z':2}
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
assumptions = {'assume01': {'fund1':10, 'fund2':15, 'fund3':12},
               'assume02': {'fund1':1000, 'fund3':950},   
               'assume03': {'fund1':3, 'fund2':2, 'fund3':3}}

def fund_assumptions(fund):
    return dict((k, assumptions[k].get(fund)) for k in assumptions)

print fund_assumptions('fund2')
#prints {'assume02': None, 'assume03': 2, 'assume01': 15}
```

Comment: This is a slick approach. My only concern is to whether it's  scalable without editing the file directly. New `assume..` variables pop up frequently that I need to add. I'm still very new to programming but I'm hoping to incorporate this `assumptions` module into a GUI environment for assumption editing and I don't know if having the dictionaries embedded in another dictionary will impact that ability. Will try it though. Many thanks.

Comment: @DolphinTsar It is good to separate data and program logic. The assumptions are data, but variable definitions are part of program logic

Answer (score 1):

I think [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) from the `collections` module is what you are looking for.

Here is an example

```
from collections import defaultdict

# you must use `lambda` here as using just `None` will result with
# KeyError on undefined keys
fund_dict = defaultdict(lambda: None, {'assume01':15, 'assume03':2})
print fund_def['assume01']  # outputs 15
print fund_def['assume02']  # outputs None
print fund_def['assume03']  # outputs 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to link multiple dictionaries together (one with default values and another with updated assumptions):

```
import UserDict

class Chainmap(UserDict.DictMixin):
    """Combine multiple mappings for successive lookups.

    For example, to emulate Python's normal lookup sequence:

        import __builtin__
        pylookup = Chainmap(locals(), globals(), vars(__builtin__))
    """

    def __init__(self, *maps):
        self._maps = maps

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        for mapping in self._maps:
            try:
                return mapping[key]
            except KeyError:
                pass
        raise KeyError(key)

    def keys(self):
        result = []
        seen = set()
        for mapping in self_maps:
            for key in mapping:
                if key not in seen:
                    result.append(key)
                    seen.add(key)
        return result
```

For a more complete dictionary interface, see init.py#l754">http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ab5d39caad6f/Lib/collections/**init**.py#l754

The *ChainMap* class could be used like this:

```
base_assumptions = dict(a1=10, a2=15, a3=30)

class FundClass:
    def __init__(self, fund, investor_assumptions)  #dict to be unpacked via '**' when passed
        combined_dict = ChainMap(investor_assumptions, base_assumptions)
        self.some_var = combined_dict['a1']
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming that assumptions is in the same directory as your script

```
import assumptions
fund = "..."
fund_dict = {}
for d in dir(assumptions):
    element = eval("assumptions." + d)
    if isinstance(element, dict) and d[6:] == "assume": # in case there are other dictionaries in the file
        if fund in element:
            fund_dict[d] = element[fund]
        else:
            fund_dict[d] = None

# using your example:
# print fund_dict prints {'assume01': 15, 'assume02': None, 'assume03': 2}
```

Comment: Ahh! This is what I've been trying to do. I was getting caught up trying to reference the assumptions module via the `module.object` approach, but wasn't using the `eval`, thus was getting an error that the iterating variable wasn't found in `assumptions`. Will try when I get home. Thanks!